# How to check which filesystem current kernel supports?

Tags: mount, filesystem

I would like to know if it's possible to check which filesystems my kernel supports. (like btrfs, raiserfs, exfat,  ...).

Man mount shows many options, but it's not really possible to use all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can easily find out what filesystem running Linux kernel supports with following command:

```
 cat /proc/filesystems
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! A *greener* answer would have been to post the text output of the command :).

Comment: Tried this and almost got the same result. I'm confused as to why ntfs and fat is not listed?

Answer (score 2):

use

```
cat /proc/filesystems
```

to check the list of file systems supported by the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

Note that file systems like btrfs may be available but they are *also* experimental, so use with caution.

Comment: Thanks for info! BTRFS looks faster than EXT4, but I am recieving some errors in dmesg.